# Troubleshooting nightmare: non-replicatable errors while webscraping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, capybara

I'm trying to run a webscraper that scrapes indeed.com and applies for jobs. What really gets me is the inconsistent, yet random errors. I'm not a programmer, but as far as I understand, if 2+2=4, then it should always be 4.

Here is the script I'm trying to run:
https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter/blob/master/scraper.rb

Seems to only work with firefox v45.0.2 because of the geckodriver

My own fixes in scraper.rb if you wish to execute the script yourself:

```
config.allow_url("indeed.com")
JobScraper.new('https://www.indeed.com/', ARGV[0], ARGV[3]).scrape(ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
```

**ERRORS**

## Example 1

```
def perform_search
# For indeed0
save_and_open_page
fill_in 'q', :with => @skillset
fill_in 'l', :with => @region
find('#fj').click
sleep(1)
end
```

Error: Unable to find class #fj. So it was able to find q, and l, but not fj.  q and l are forms while fj is a button. How was it able to find the forms but not the button...????? Re-executed code via the terminal command `rails server` and the error went away. later came back again, how random in nature!!!! How is this possible? I can't even predict when it will happen so i can `save_and_open_page`

## Example 2: error comes up when you run a search. no jobs get posted.

Error: block passed to #window_opened _by opened 0 windows instead of 1 (Capybara::Window Error)
Re-execute code, error went away, later comes back...

### To clarify on example 2:

That error sometimes comes up since I have a Canadian IP address and it redirects me to indeed.ca. However, when used a US ip address via a VPN, that error was consistent 100% of the time. In an attempt to work around this, i've modified the code to go to the US version of the site, again, that error is consistent 100% of the time. Any idea on why this window is not popping up when i'm on the US version of indeed.com?

Summary:
i'm not necessarily looking for solutions, but an understanding of what is going on. Why the randomness in error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2+2=4 under a given set of assumptions and conditions.  Browsers and scrapers unfortunately aren't that predictable, with random delays, page throttling, changing pages, varying support levels for different technologies, etc.

In your current case the reason for the `window_opened_by` error could have been not having `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` set long enough (how long Capybara will wait for the window to open), however if you try the search manually you'll see that `indeed` no longer opens the job description in a new window if the current window is wide enough to show it in a right panel.  Basically the code you're trying to use is no longer fully compatible with `indeed.com` due to changes in how `indeed.com` works.  You could fix this by setting the drivers window size to a size where indeed.com will always open a new window, or by setting the window size big enough job descriptions open on the same page and rewriting the code to not look for a new window.

As for the no '#fj' issue, the easiest way to debug that is to put

```
save_and_open_screenshot if page.has_no_css?('#fj')
```

before the `find('#fj').click` and see what the page looks like when there is no '#fj' element on it. Doing that shows `indeed.com` is randomly returning the mobile site. Why this is happening I have no idea, but it could just be what `indeed.com` does when it doesn't recognize the current user agent.  If that's the case you can probably work around that by setting the user agent the capybara-webkit driver uses, or you could just switch to calling `click_button('Find Jobs')` which should click the button on both the mobile and non-mobile pages.

Comment: You nailed it. How would I set the window size. I followed the instructions here yet get a blank page (a big page pops up and is then resized into a smaller one even though i only set the size via dimentional struct'). http://yizeng.me/2014/02/23/how-to-get-window-size-resize-or-maximize-window-using-selenium-webdriver/#ruby-example

Comment: @AlannaMueller If you're using the code you linked to in the question then you're using `capybara-webkit` as the driver, not `selenium`, so nothing on that page is relevant (It's also not really relevant when using selenium any more either since it was written in 2014) .  With `capybara-webkit` you should be able to do `current_window.resize_to(1280,1024)` (or whatever dimensions you want) before calling `visit`

Comment: I apologize for not paying enough attention to notice that, shows my lack of experience. Thank you so much for the help. All that is left to do is setting the user agent to make adding further modifications painless. Thanks for the educational input Thomas.